# Electric field at the surface of a conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors, boundary-conditions

Elecric field near the surface of a conductor is

$$E= \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}.$$

What is instead the electric field on the surface itself of the conductor? Just inside the surface, in the conductor, $E$ should be zero; just outside, however, there is the above electric field. What happens at the points of the surface? They still belong to the conductor, but they are the limiting points of its volume.

Comment: Without considering the microscopic aspects of the situation, there is a discontinuity in the electric field at the surface.

Comment: @Farcher Thanks! When in basic problems they ask to calculate the potential between two conductors (let's say concentric hollow spheres) differently charged, what should I assume about the electric field at one side of the integration?